# Django two-column form

Tags: django, forms, templates

What is the most pythonic way to implement django ModelForm for model with 9 fields, which will be split into two columns in the template? Something like this:

```
<form>
    <div class="column-1">
        5 fields for column 1
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
        4 fields for column 2
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest and cleanest way is to stick to the methods outlined in the docs...

```
<form>
    <div class="column-1">
       {{ form.field1 }}
       ...
       {{ form.field5 }}       
    </div>
    <div class="column-2"> 
       {{ form.field6 }}
       ...
       {{ form.field9 }}
       </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This way I need to hardcode fields into template, which feels wrong.

Comment: Definitely. How your template renders the fields of the form has nothing to do with the Python code behind the form. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template

Comment: @Shark: It's not even remotely "wrong". If Django didn't provide convenience methods for you like `as_ul` or `as_p`, this would be how you would have to do it anyways. True, you lose a bit of abstraction by rendering the fields individually, but that's the price of wanting to *display* them differently.

Comment: Ah, right, so presentation layer must be defined in templates, that's what they are for :)

Comment: I agree, but Django itself provides a way to do it via the ModelAdmin fieldsets. IMHO, Django forms have two sides: they are validators and they are the bridge between models and templates (they provide widgets and 'as_ul/table', which are "presentation" things).

Comment: @ChrisPratt Whilst not 'wrong' per se - it can be argued it's a bit clunky and un-Djangonic.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - no - I was disagreeing with you saying "It's not even remotely 'wrong'". i.e. I'm saying it is a bit wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You can use carljm's [django-form-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-form-utils) which allows you to define fieldsets. You can specify a class for each fieldset as you like. You'll still have to list all your fields in the form definition, though.

Comment: Crispy-forms is worth a look also.